# How can I modify JSON object from a column while retrieving the data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, open-json

I have a JSON array object like below in a SQL Server table column:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "test1",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Red",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "White",
      "DatesToRemember": "2022-03-03T00:00:00"
    },
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Grenn",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "Black",
      "DatesToRemember": "2022-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

I want to check whether the `DatesToRemember` is array, or not if it is not string of array, then I want to retrieve it as shown here:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "test1",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Red",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "White",
      "DatesToRemember": ["2022-03-03T00:00:00"]
    },
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Grenn",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "Black",
      "DatesToRemember": ["2022-01-01T00:00:00"]
    },
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

How can I write a query to achieve the output?

Please help to get through this

Comment: ...how is that "modifying" the JSON data? (And your use-case does not look like a good reason for storing JSON in an RDBMS - why aren't you normalizing this data and using RDBMS as Codd intended?)

Comment: if json structure doesnt change the you may try replacing `"DatesToRemember":"` with `"DatesToRemember":["` And `"},"gender":` with `"]},"gender":`... But this is an ugly way of storing and retrieving

Comment: The structure does not matter i am looking for a good approach instead of replace approach like using Openjson or something like that i am not familiar with that

Comment: @saikrishna If you want a "good approach" then you should _not_ be storing JSON in an RDBMS table in the first place.

Comment: Does the stored JSON always have this fixed structure?

Comment: @Dai I am not practicing it ,its real time

Comment: @Zhorov Yes the the JSON always has the Fixed structure

Answer (score 0):

first ,You can parse the whole json

And then parse the section with array filed DatesToRemember

And finally, compare all name with  name isarray and extract name isnotarray  with join

The table ListName : contains all the data

the table CheckArray: contains only the data array DatesToRemember

```
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max)=N'[
  {
    "Name": "test1",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Red",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "White",
      "DatesToRemember": ["2022-03-03T00:00:00"]
    },
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Grenn",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "Black",
      "DatesToRemember": "d"
    },
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
';
with CheckArray as(
        
        select distinct Name from OPENJSON(@json)
        WITH( 
        Name VARCHAR(20) '$.Name' ,

        DatesToRememberJson nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Favouties.DatesToRemember' AS JSON)
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DatesToRememberJson
        ) WITH (

        DatesToRemember VARCHAR(20) '$'
        )
        
),
ListName as (
                select Name from OPENJSON(@json)
                WITH( 
                Name VARCHAR(20) '$.Name'
                )
)
select 
          b.[Name]
        , iif( a.[Name] is null,'Is not array','IS array') as TypeArray 
from CheckArray a
right join ListName  b on a.[Name]=b.[Name]
--where a.[Name] is null

| Name | TypeArray  |
| -----| -----------|
| test1|IS array    |
| test2|Is not array|
```

You can Show  all json   with the following codes

```
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max)=N'[
  {
    "Name": "test1",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Red",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "White",
      "DatesToRemember": ["2022-03-03T00:00:00"]
    },
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Favouties": {
      "LikedColor": "Grenn",
      "ReasonsToLike": "None",
      "HatedColor": "Black",
      "DatesToRemember": "d"
    },
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
';
 
select * from OPENJSON(@json)
WITH( 
Name VARCHAR(20) '$.Name' ,
gender VARCHAR(20) '$.gender',
LikedColor VARCHAR(20) '$.Favouties.LikedColor',
ReasonsToLike VARCHAR(20) '$.Favouties.ReasonsToLike',
HatedColor VARCHAR(20) '$.Favouties.HatedColor',

DatesToRememberJson nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Favouties.DatesToRemember' AS JSON)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DatesToRememberJson
) WITH (

DatesToRemember VARCHAR(20) '$'
)
```

Comment: When i run your queries it is showing what you said it would show but i am not sure how do i exactly use this code to achieve my desired output